# Get the width of an element and use it to set its height

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I'm using Bootstrap's grid system, and I set the `<iframe>` width to 90%.

The problem is how can I set the height of `<iframe>` accrodingly? 
For example, I want a 16:9 size. But I dont know how can I get the value of the width

Code may look like:

```
iframe
 width: 90%
 height: $(width)*9/16
```

Comment: I think you may need to use javascript for this

Comment: Yes, I think it could be done with js. But I feel that this kind of thing should be done with css, since its just width and height....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with pure CSS, it's called [intrinsic ratios](http://alistapart.com/article/creating-intrinsic-ratios-for-video). It requires doing math, but with SASS and Compass you can just say what you want and get the result! :D

You'll need a wrapper:

```
<div class=iframe-container>
  <iframe></iframe>
</div>
```

SASS + Compass:

```
@import toolkit

.iframe-container
  +intrinsic-ratio(16/9, 90%)
```

Demo: http://sassbin.com/gist/5983091/

As you can see, the awesome [Toolkit](https://github.com/Team-Sass/toolkit#intrinsic-ratios) Compass extension is used.

Comment: It would be helpful for future users if you showed *why* this works the way it does.  Where does `toolkit` come from?

Comment: I have: 1. given a link to a very detailed explaination of the intrinsic ratios concept, 2. povided a link to the Toolkit's home page and its documentation of the intrinsic ratios mixin, 3. noted that Toolkit is a Compass extension, 4. created SassBin and used it to share a demo where CSS code is displayed. Is there really anything on the subject that is not covered by my answer?

Answer (score 1):

man, that guy beat me to it, but he's right you could do it with JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('iframe').height(function() { 
        return $(this).width()*(9/16);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use JQuery:

```
$('.iframe').height($('.iframe').width()*(9/16));
```

Make sure you have a js file though